# How to batch convert "M4A" files to "MP3" with Python?

Tags: python, converters

The issue is clear, how can I convert "M4A" files to "MP3" with Python?

Actually, what I'm searching for is a code that will convert files in batches, but I wouldn't say no to a code that works singly.

I have searched on the internet about this subject, but subsequently I could not reach a clear conclusion.

Comment: Why not just use `ffmpeg`?

Comment: executing [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) command for conversion using subprocess is one way, you use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) for batching.